# Fastest way to expand bits in a field to all (overlapping + adjacent) set bits in a mask?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, sse, avx

Say I have 2 binary inputs named IN and MASK. Actual field size could be 32 to 256 bits depending on what instruction set is used to accomplish the task. Both inputs change every call.

```
Inputs:
IN   = ...1100010010010100...
MASK = ...0001111010111011...
Output:
OUT  = ...0001111010111000...
```

edit: another example result from some comment discussion

```
IN   = ...11111110011010110...
MASK = ...01011011001111110...
Output:
OUT  = ...01011011001111110...
```

I want to get the contiguous adjacent 1 bits of MASK that a 1 bit of IN is within. (Is there a general term for this kind of operation? Maybe I'm not phrasing my searches properly.) I'm trying to find a way to do this that is a bit faster. I'm open to using any x86 or x86 SIMD extensions that can get this done in minimum cpu cycles. A wider data type SIMD is preferred as it will allow me to process more data at once.

The best naive solution I've come up with is the following pseudocode, which manually shifts left until there are no more matching bits, then repeats shifting right:

```
// (using the variables above)
testL = testR = OUT = (IN & MASK);

LoopL:
testL = (testL << 1) & MASK;
if (testL != 0) {
    OUT = OUT | testL;
    goto LoopL;
}

LoopR:
testR = (testR >> 1) & MASK;
if (testR != 0) {
    OUT = OUT | testR;
    goto LoopR;
}

return OUT;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select spans of set bits in a bitmask that overlap with a 1-bit in a selector bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37313982/select-spans-of-set-bits-in-a-bitmask-that-overlap-with-a-1-bit-in-a-selector-bi)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194570/discussion-on-question-by-muusbolla-fastest-way-to-expand-bits-in-a-field-to-all).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess @fuz comment was on the right track.
The following example shows how the SSE and AVX2 code below works.
The algorithm starts with `IN_reduced = IN & MASK` because we are not interested 
in `IN` bits at positions where `MASK` is `0`.

```
IN                                  = . . . 0 0 0 0 . . . . p q r s . . .
MASK                                = . . 0 1 1 1 1 0 . . 0 1 1 1 1 0 . . 
IN_reduced = IN & MASK              = . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 . . 0 p q r s 0 . .
```

If any of the `p q r s` bits is `1`, then `IN_reduced + MASK` has a carry bit `1` 
at position `X`, which is right left to the 
requested contiguous bits.

```
MASK                                = . . 0 1 1 1 1 0 . . 0 1 1 1 1 0 . . 
IN_reduced                          = . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 . . 0 p q r s 0 . .
IN_reduced + MASK                   = . . 0 1 1 1 1 . . . 1 . . . . . .
                                                          X
(IN_reduced + MASK) >>1             = . . . 0 1 1 1 1 . . . 1 . . . . . .
```

With `>> 1` this carry bit `1` is shifted to the same column as bit `p` 
(the first bit of the contiguous bits).
Now, `(IN_reduced + MASK) >>1` is actually an average of `IN_reduced` and `MASK`. 
In order to avoid possible overflow of addition we use the following
average: `avg(a, b) = (a & b) + ((a ^ b) >> 1)` (See @Harold's comment,
see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14884757) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10470235).)
With `average = avg(IN_reduced, MASK)` we get

```
MASK                                = . . 0 1 1 1 1 0 . . 0 1 1 1 1 0 . . 
IN_reduced                          = . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 . . 0 p q r s 0 . .
average                             = . . . 0 1 1 1 1 . . . 1 . . . . . .
MASK >> 1                           = . . . 0 1 1 1 1 0 . . 0 1 1 1 1 0 .  
leading_bits = (~(MASK>>1))&average = . . . 0 0 0 0 0 . . . 1 0 0 0 0 . .
```

We can isolate the leading carry bits with
`leading_bits = (~(MASK>>1) ) & average` because `MASK>>1` is zero at the positions 
of the carry bits 
that we are interested in.

With normal addition the carry propagates from right to left. Here we use a
reverse addition: with a carry from left to right.
Reverse adding `MASK` and `leading_bits`: 
`rev_added = bit_swap(bit_swap(MASK) + bit_swap(leading_bits))`,
This zeros the bits at 
the wanted positions.
With `OUT = (~rev_added) & MASK` we get the result.

```
MASK                                = . . 0 1 1 1 1 0 . . 0 1 1 1 1 0 . . 
leading_bits                        = . . . 0 0 0 0 0 . . . 1 0 0 0 0 . .  
rev_added (MASK,leading_bits)       = . . . 1 1 1 1 0 . . . 0 0 0 0 1 . .
OUT = ~rev_added & MASK             = . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 . . . 1 1 1 1 0 . .
```

The algorithm was not thoroughly tested, but the output looks ok.

---

The code block below contains two separate codes:
The upper half is the SSE code, 
and the lower half is the AVX2 code. 
(In order to avoid 
bloating the answer too much with two large code blocks.) 
The SSE algorithm works with 2 x 64-bit elements and the AVX2 version works with 4 x 64-bit elements.

With gcc 9.1, the algorithm [compiles to about 29 instructions](https://godbolt.org/z/KWeNzc),
aside from 4 `vmovdqa`-s for loading some constants, which are likely 
hoisted out of the loop in a real world application (after inlining).
These 29 instructions are a good mix of  9 shuffles (`vpshufb`) that execute 
on port 5 (p5) on Intel Skylake, and many other instructions that often may 
execute on p0, p1 or p5.

Therefore, a performance of about 3 instructions per cycle might be possible. 
In that case the throughput would be about 1 function call (inlined) 
per 10 cycles. In the AVX2 case this means 4 `uint64_t` `OUT` results per 
about 10 cycles.

Note that the performance is independent of the data(!), which is a great 
benefit of this answer I think. The solution is branchless, and loopless, and
cannot suffer from failing branch prediction.

```c
/*  gcc -O3 -m64 -Wall -march=skylake select_bits.c    */
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int print_sse_128_bin(__m128i x);
__m128i bit_128_k(unsigned int k);
__m128i mm_bitreverse_epi64(__m128i x);
__m128i mm_revadd_epi64(__m128i x, __m128i y);


/* Select specific pieces of contiguous bits from `MASK` based on selector `IN`  */
__m128i mm_select_bits_epi64(__m128i IN, __m128i MASK){
    __m128i IN_reduced   = _mm_and_si128(IN, MASK);
    /* Compute the average of IN_reduced and MASK with avg(a,b)=(a&b)+((a^b)>>1)  */
    /* (IN_reduced & MASK) + ((IN_reduced ^ MASK) >>1) =                          */
    /* ((IN & MASK) & MASK) + ((IN_reduced ^ MASK) >>1) =                         */
    /* IN_reduced + ((IN_reduced ^ MASK) >>1)                                     */
    __m128i tmp          = _mm_xor_si128(IN_reduced, MASK);
    __m128i tmp_div2     = _mm_srli_epi64(tmp, 1);
    __m128i average      = _mm_add_epi64(IN_reduced, tmp_div2);   /* average is the average */
    __m128i MASK_div2    = _mm_srli_epi64(MASK, 1);
    __m128i leading_bits = _mm_andnot_si128(MASK_div2, average);
    __m128i rev_added    = mm_revadd_epi64(MASK, leading_bits);
    __m128i OUT          = _mm_andnot_si128(rev_added, MASK);
    /* Uncomment the next lines to check the arithmetic */ /*   
    printf("IN           ");print_sse_128_bin(IN           );       
    printf("MASK         ");print_sse_128_bin(MASK         ); 
    printf("IN_reduced   ");print_sse_128_bin(IN_reduced   );       
    printf("tmp          ");print_sse_128_bin(tmp          );       
    printf("tmp_div2     ");print_sse_128_bin(tmp_div2     );       
    printf("average      ");print_sse_128_bin(average      );       
    printf("MASK_div2    ");print_sse_128_bin(MASK_div2    );       
    printf("leading_bits ");print_sse_128_bin(leading_bits );       
    printf("rev_added    ");print_sse_128_bin(rev_added    );       
    printf("OUT          ");print_sse_128_bin(OUT          );       
    printf("\n");*/
    return OUT;       
}


int main(){
    __m128i IN   = _mm_set_epi64x(0b11111110011010110, 0b1100010010010100);
    __m128i MASK = _mm_set_epi64x(0b01011011001111110, 0b0001111010111011);
    __m128i OUT;    

    printf("Example 1 \n");
    OUT = mm_select_bits_epi64(IN, MASK);
    printf("IN           ");print_sse_128_bin(IN);
    printf("MASK         ");print_sse_128_bin(MASK);
    printf("OUT          ");print_sse_128_bin(OUT);
    printf("\n\n");

                      /*  0b7654321076543210765432107654321076543210765432107654321076543210  */
    IN   = _mm_set_epi64x(0b1000001001001010000010000000100000010000000000100000000111100011, 
                          0b11111110011010111);
    MASK = _mm_set_epi64x(0b1110011110101110111111000000000111011111101101111100011111000001, 
                          0b01011011001111111);

    printf("Example 2 \n");
    OUT = mm_select_bits_epi64(IN, MASK);
    printf("IN           ");print_sse_128_bin(IN);
    printf("MASK         ");print_sse_128_bin(MASK);
    printf("OUT          ");print_sse_128_bin(OUT);
    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}


int print_sse_128_bin(__m128i x){
    for (int i = 127; i >= 0; i--){
        printf("%1u", _mm_testnzc_si128(bit_128_k(i), x));
        if (((i & 7) == 0) && (i > 0)) printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}


/* From my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39595704/2439725, adapted to 128-bit */
inline __m128i bit_128_k(unsigned int k){
  __m128i  indices     = _mm_set_epi32(96, 64, 32, 0);
  __m128i  one         = _mm_set1_epi32(1);

  __m128i  kvec        = _mm_set1_epi32(k);  
  __m128i  shiftcounts = _mm_sub_epi32(kvec, indices);
  __m128i  kbit        = _mm_sllv_epi32(one, shiftcounts);   
  return kbit;                             
}


/* Copied from Harold's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46318399/2439725         */
/* Adapted to epi64 and __m128i: bit reverse two 64 bit elements                    */
inline __m128i mm_bitreverse_epi64(__m128i x){
    __m128i shufbytes = _mm_setr_epi8(7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8); 
    __m128i luthigh = _mm_setr_epi8(0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15);
    __m128i lutlow = _mm_slli_epi16(luthigh, 4);
    __m128i lowmask = _mm_set1_epi8(15);
    __m128i rbytes = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x, shufbytes);
    __m128i high = _mm_shuffle_epi8(lutlow, _mm_and_si128(rbytes, lowmask));
    __m128i low = _mm_shuffle_epi8(luthigh, _mm_and_si128(_mm_srli_epi16(rbytes, 4), lowmask));
    return _mm_or_si128(low, high);
}


/* Add in the reverse direction: With a carry from left to */
/* right, instead of right to left                         */
inline __m128i mm_revadd_epi64(__m128i x, __m128i y){
    x = mm_bitreverse_epi64(x);
    y = mm_bitreverse_epi64(y);
    __m128i sum = _mm_add_epi64(x, y);
    return mm_bitreverse_epi64(sum);
}
/* End of SSE code */


/************* AVX2 code starts here ********************************************/

/*  gcc -O3 -m64 -Wall -march=skylake select_bits256.c    */
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int print_avx_256_bin(__m256i x);
__m256i bit_256_k(unsigned int k);
__m256i mm256_bitreverse_epi64(__m256i x);
__m256i mm256_revadd_epi64(__m256i x, __m256i y);


/* Select specific pieces of contiguous bits from `MASK` based on selector `IN`  */
__m256i mm256_select_bits_epi64(__m256i IN, __m256i MASK){
    __m256i IN_reduced   = _mm256_and_si256(IN, MASK);
    /* Compute the average of IN_reduced and MASK with avg(a,b)=(a&b)+((a^b)>>1)  */
    /* (IN_reduced & MASK) + ((IN_reduced ^ MASK) >>1) =                          */
    /* ((IN & MASK) & MASK) + ((IN_reduced ^ MASK) >>1) =                         */
    /* IN_reduced + ((IN_reduced ^ MASK) >>1)                                     */
    __m256i tmp          = _mm256_xor_si256(IN_reduced, MASK);
    __m256i tmp_div2     = _mm256_srli_epi64(tmp, 1);
    __m256i average      = _mm256_add_epi64(IN_reduced, tmp_div2);   /* average is the average */
    __m256i MASK_div2    = _mm256_srli_epi64(MASK, 1);
    __m256i leading_bits = _mm256_andnot_si256(MASK_div2, average);
    __m256i rev_added    = mm256_revadd_epi64(MASK, leading_bits);
    __m256i OUT          = _mm256_andnot_si256(rev_added, MASK);
    /* Uncomment the next lines to check the arithmetic */ /*   
    printf("IN           ");print_avx_256_bin(IN           );       
    printf("MASK         ");print_avx_256_bin(MASK         ); 
    printf("IN_reduced   ");print_avx_256_bin(IN_reduced   );       
    printf("tmp          ");print_avx_256_bin(tmp          );       
    printf("tmp_div2     ");print_avx_256_bin(tmp_div2     );       
    printf("average      ");print_avx_256_bin(average      );       
    printf("MASK_div2    ");print_avx_256_bin(MASK_div2    );       
    printf("leading_bits ");print_avx_256_bin(leading_bits );       
    printf("rev_added    ");print_avx_256_bin(rev_added    );       
    printf("OUT          ");print_avx_256_bin(OUT          );       
    printf("\n");*/
    return OUT;       
}


int main(){
    __m256i IN   = _mm256_set_epi64x(0b11111110011010110, 
                                     0b1100010010010100,
                                     0b1000001001001010000010000000100000010000000000100000000111100011, 
                                     0b11111110011010111
    );
    __m256i MASK = _mm256_set_epi64x(0b01011011001111110, 
                                     0b0001111010111011,
                                     0b1110011110101110111111000000000111011111101101111100011111000001, 
                                     0b01011011001111111);
    __m256i OUT;    

    printf("Example \n");
    OUT = mm256_select_bits_epi64(IN, MASK);
    printf("IN           ");print_avx_256_bin(IN);
    printf("MASK         ");print_avx_256_bin(MASK);
    printf("OUT          ");print_avx_256_bin(OUT);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}


int print_avx_256_bin(__m256i x){
    for (int i=255;i>=0;i--){
        printf("%1u",_mm256_testnzc_si256(bit_256_k(i),x));
        if (((i&7) ==0)&&(i>0)) printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}


/* From my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39595704/2439725 */
inline __m256i bit_256_k(unsigned int k){
  __m256i  indices     = _mm256_set_epi32(224,192,160,128,96,64,32,0);
  __m256i  one         = _mm256_set1_epi32(1);

  __m256i  kvec        = _mm256_set1_epi32(k);  
  __m256i  shiftcounts = _mm256_sub_epi32(kvec, indices);
  __m256i  kbit        = _mm256_sllv_epi32(one, shiftcounts);   
  return kbit;                             
}


/* Copied from Harold's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46318399/2439725         */
/* Adapted to epi64: bit reverse four 64 bit elements                    */
inline __m256i mm256_bitreverse_epi64(__m256i x){
    __m256i shufbytes = _mm256_setr_epi8(7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8);
    __m256i luthigh = _mm256_setr_epi8(0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15, 0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15);
    __m256i lutlow = _mm256_slli_epi16(luthigh, 4);
    __m256i lowmask = _mm256_set1_epi8(15);
    __m256i rbytes = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(x, shufbytes);
    __m256i high = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(lutlow, _mm256_and_si256(rbytes, lowmask));
    __m256i low = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(luthigh, _mm256_and_si256(_mm256_srli_epi16(rbytes, 4), lowmask));
    return _mm256_or_si256(low, high);
}


/* Add in the reverse direction: With a carry from left to */
/* right, instead of right to left                         */
inline __m256i mm256_revadd_epi64(__m256i x, __m256i y){
    x = mm256_bitreverse_epi64(x);
    y = mm256_bitreverse_epi64(y);
    __m256i sum = _mm256_add_epi64(x, y);
    return mm256_bitreverse_epi64(sum);
}
```

Output of the SSE code with an uncommented debugging section:

```
Example 1 
IN           00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 11111100 11010110 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 11000100 10010100
MASK         00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 10110110 01111110 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00011110 10111011
IN_reduced   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 10110100 01010110 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000100 10010000
tmp          00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010 00101000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00011010 00101011
tmp_div2     00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 00010100 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001101 00010101
average      00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 10110101 01101010 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00010001 10100101
MASK_div2    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 01011011 00111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001111 01011101
leading_bits 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 10100100 01000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00010000 10100000
rev_added    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 01001001 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 01000111
OUT          00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 10110110 01111110 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00011110 10111000

IN           00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 11111100 11010110 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 11000100 10010100
MASK         00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 10110110 01111110 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00011110 10111011
OUT          00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 10110110 01111110 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00011110 10111000


Example 2 
IN           10000010 01001010 00001000 00001000 00010000 00000010 00000001 11100011 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 11111100 11010111
MASK         11100111 10101110 11111100 00000001 11011111 10110111 11000111 11000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 10110110 01111111
IN_reduced   10000010 00001010 00001000 00000000 00010000 00000010 00000001 11000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 10110100 01010111
tmp          01100101 10100100 11110100 00000001 11001111 10110101 11000110 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010 00101000
tmp_div2     00110010 11010010 01111010 00000000 11100111 11011010 11100011 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 00010100
average      10110100 11011100 10000010 00000000 11110111 11011100 11100100 11000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 10110101 01101011
MASK_div2    01110011 11010111 01111110 00000000 11101111 11011011 11100011 11100000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 01011011 00111111
leading_bits 10000100 00001000 10000000 00000000 00010000 00000100 00000100 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 10100100 01000000
rev_added    00010000 01100001 00000010 00000001 11000000 01110000 00100000 00100000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 01001001 00000000
OUT          11100111 10001110 11111100 00000000 00011111 10000111 11000111 11000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 10110110 01111111

IN           10000010 01001010 00001000 00001000 00010000 00000010 00000001 11100011 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 11111100 11010111
MASK         11100111 10101110 11111100 00000001 11011111 10110111 11000111 11000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 10110110 01111111
OUT          11100111 10001110 11111100 00000000 00011111 10000111 11000111 11000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 10110110 01111111
```

Comment: Too bad there isn't a `pavgq`, only [`pavgb/w`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pavgb:pavgw)

Comment: @PeterCordes: Right. Although the rounding behavior of `pavgb/w` is different from the one used here. In general I would prefer `average = (a / 2) + (b / 2) + (a & b & 1)`.

Comment: Oh, I see, yours always rounds the average down, instead of to even with `(a+b+1) >> 1`.  So yours is like `(a+b) >> 1` with an extra bit for the sum.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Yes. With two `uint64_t` as inputs it rounds down (truncates) the result. Moreover, it cannot overflow. (With `(a+b) >> 1` you may lose the carry bit.) Probably `pavgb/w` was easier to implement by Intel as it is, or it was designed for some specific use case.

Comment: Given the 2 sizes available and that they date back to Pentium 3's new MMX instructions (before the SSE2 XMM versions), I think the obvious use-cases were 50/50 mixing linear PCM audio or 50/50 blending pixels.  When I wrote `(a+b)>>1` I was of course still talking about doing `a+b` with an extra bit of precision, like `pavgw` does.  (They document it as a 17-bit sum before the right shift, because that's the easy way to think about it when you aren't constrained by fixed-width types or registers.  But it makes it hard to describe with normal notation.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: Indeed it is quite likely that they had audio and video applications in mind with `pavgb/w`, interesting.

Comment: There's also `(a&b)+((a^b)>>1)` for the average (and for b/w, `~pavgb(~a, ~b)`)

Comment: Being branchless and loopless, makes this the superior answer. Chapeau! My own answer is only interesting on architectures that do not have a dedicated instruction for bitwise reversal.

Comment: @harold: Nice formula, quite advanced. I had not seen it before. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The following approach needs only a single loop, with the number of iterations equal to the number of 'groups' found.
I don't know if it will be more efficient than your approach; there's 6 arith/bitwise operations in each iteration.

In pseudo code (C-like):

```
OUT = 0;
a = MASK;
while (a)
{
    e = a & ~(a + (a & (-a)));
    if (e & IN) OUT |= e;
    a ^= e;
}
```

Here's how it works, step by step, using 11010111 as an example mask:

```
OUT = 0

a = MASK        11010111
c = a & (-a)    00000001   keeps rightmost one only
d = a + c       11011000   clears rightmost group (and set the bit to its immediate left)
e = a & ~d      00000111   keeps rightmost group only

if (e & IN) OUT |= e;      adds group to OUT

a = a ^ e       11010000   clears rightmost group, so we can proceed with the next group
c = a & (-a)    00010000
d = a + c       11100000
e = a & ~d      00010000

if (e & IN) OUT |= e;

a = a ^ e       11000000
c = a & (-a)    01000000
d = a + c       00000000   (ignoring carry when adding)
e = a & ~d      11000000

if (e & IN) OUT |= e;

a = a ^ e       00000000   done
```

As pointed out @PeterCordes, some operations could be optimized using x86 BMI1 instructions:

- `c = a & (-a)`: [blsi](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/blsi)
- `e = a & ~d`: [andn](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/andn)

This approach is good for processor architectures that do not support bitwise reversal. On architectures that do have a dedicated instruction to reverse the order of bits in an integer, [wim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56478996/) is more efficient.

Comment: You can isolate the lowest set bit in fewer operations, just `(-n) & n`.  x86 BMI1 has an instruction for that (which compilers know how to use when optimizing that expression): [`blsi`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/blsi).  Single-cycle latency on Intel CPUs, 2 uops / 2 cycle latency on AMD Ryzen.  (Down from 3 for `mov` / `neg` / `and` without BMI1).  BMI1 `andn` (and not) also implement `(~d) & a`, so again super helpful here.

Comment: Or *if* the mask groups can avoid crossing 64-bit boundaries, this can vectorize with SSE2 or AVX2 like the OP was hoping, using `(v)paddq` for the `-n` and `a+c` operations to clear the lowest group.  (And then the run time scales with the number of groups per element, not total.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I updated my answer according to your comment. Thanks, very clever!

Comment: Heh, I only know that there's a trick for lowest-set isolate because of the BMI1 instruction set.  When I want to remember the bithack for it, I look up the Operation section of [`blsi`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/blsi), Bit Lowest Set Isolate. :P  I can normally remember the BLSR Bit Lowest Set: Reset trick `n & (n-1)` though; that's certainly the more well-known and easier to grok one.

Comment: MSVC with /O2 and /arch:AVX2 does generate blsi and andn for those parts of this algorithm.

Comment: So Microsoft did their homework on this one. Thank you for the follow-up!